# Notepad++ editing is replacing the text instead of writing it in between

Tags: notepad++, editor

I am new to using notepad ++, so this seems like a simple problem but i dont know how to fix it. If i have a file in notepad ++ and if I want to go change something in it, when i go to that line and type something it replaces the character in place for what i type instead of moving it to the right like say word or any text editor. This makes it so that I'll have to type out the whole line again. Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is not related to notepad++. Press `ins` (insert) key and that's all.

Comment: oh that was simple enough, thanks for the reply.